# How to plot scatter points using pgfplots with color defined from table rgb values?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color, pgfplotstable, metadata

I am trying to plot a set of data points (`scatter` points not linked to each other), where each point has a different color. The color definition is given by predefined `rgb` values written in the same file that contains the data.

The following file serves as example:

```
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.dat}
    x   y   RED   GREEN   BLUE
    1   11  0.2    0.3    0.5
    2   14  0.3    0.3    0.4
    4   26  0.1    0.8    0.1
    3   39  0.0    0.1    0.9
\end{filecontents}
```

The `x` and `y` columns represent the position of the points I want to plot. The next three columns `RED`, `GREEN` and `BLUE` correspond to the associated color values in `rgb` format.

What I was trying so far, was to do:

```
\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{test.dat}\test
%number of points to be plotted
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\test}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\N}{\pgfplotsretval-1}  

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xmin=0, xmax=5,
    ymin=0, ymax=45,
    width=8cm,
    height=6cm,
    grid=both,
    xlabel=Xtest, 
    ylabel=Ytest,   
    ]
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\N}
    {
    \definecolor{testcolor}{rgb}{\thisrow{3}, \thisrow{4}, \thisrow{5}}   
    \addplot[scatter, 
        only marks,     
        scatter/use mapped color={draw=none,fill=testcolor},
    ] 
    table [x index = 0,y index = 1]{\test};
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But I am unable to fetch a single row value for the color definition. How can I do this ? I also looked at `meta` options, but the color is defined with a single value (linearly) and I need the three components in the color definition.

Comment: ugly alternative but if you're able to read only columns, you could try to write your *.dat file the following way: `x | y | RED1 | GREEN1 | BLUE1 | RED2 | GREEN2 etc.` where x and y are columns of n elements, but RED1, GREEN1 etc are columns of only 1 element...  This would result in a file with 3*n+2 rows, but it might be better than nothing!

Comment: @anderstood In this case I guess I would also need to split `x` and `y` as `x1 | y1 | RED1 | GREEN1 | BLUE1 | x2 | y2 | ...` It's not really what I'm looking for. There has to be a way to read the table row by row...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While it is possible to access table elements by means of `\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{RED}\of{\test}`, I would recommend to move the code which defines colors into the `\addplot` command: pgfplots supports advanced `scatter` plots in which you can define how each scatter point it is to be drawn. This is more efficient in TeX.

A solution could be

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xmin=0, xmax=5,
    ymin=0, ymax=45,
    width=8cm,
    height=6cm,
    grid=both,
    xlabel=Xtest, 
    ylabel=Ytest,   
    ]
    \addplot[
        scatter,%
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={%
            \edef\temp{\noexpand\definecolor{mapped color}{rgb}{\pgfplotspointmeta}}%
            \temp
            \scope[draw=mapped color!80!black,fill=mapped color]%
        },%
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={%
            \endscope
        },%
        only marks,     
        mark=*,
        point meta={TeX code symbolic={%
            \edef\pgfplotspointmeta{\thisrow{RED},\thisrow{GREEN},\thisrow{BLUE}}%
        }},
    ] 
    table {
    x   y   RED   GREEN   BLUE
    1   11  0.2    0.3    0.5
    2   14  0.3    0.3    0.4
    4   26  0.1    0.8    0.1
    3   39  0.0    0.1    0.9
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `\addplot table {<inline data>};` to reduce the amount of code (which is, however, equivalent to `\addplot ... table {\test};`). The key points are:

- I added `mark=*` since `scatter` does not necessarily assign a plot mark as default.
- I used the keys `pre marker code` and `post marker code` to define the colors. This is precisely the same way how the default `scatter` implementation works. In our case, I used `\definecolor{rgb}{\pgfplotspointmeta}`, assuming that `\pgfplotspointmeta` contains something of sorts `<R>,<G>,<B>`.
- Finally, the complicated `point meta` expression defines `\pgfplotspointmeta` in the expected way.
- Note that we cannot simply insert `\thisrow{RED},...` into `\definecolor` here: `\thisrow` is only valid while `pgfplots` iterates over the table's row - and it does that just once when it surveys the input coordinates.
- The macro `\edef` means "expanded definition": `\edef\temp{...}` defines `\temp` to contain the expanded argument. `\noexpand` means to *not* expand the following macro in this context.
- `point meta={TeX code symbolic={<code which defines \pgfplotspointmeta}}` allows us to inject some TeX code to define a symbol - in our case a color triplet.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and explanations. It worked smoothly !

Comment: It seems that using `\addplot ... table {\test};` returns an error (missing number, treated as zero <to be read again> t). I included the table as in the OP and loaded `\pgfplotstableread{test.dat}{\data}`, see http://hastebin.com/yafimoziru.tex. I must say I see no reason for this.

Comment: I'm also getting the same "missing number, ..." error when loading from a file. Any suggestions please?