# Define colours of markers of scatterplot by rgb-values

Tags: pgfplots

I want to colour the markers of a `scatter3` plot in specified colours with rgb values. I tried it before in the following way:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
    \begin{axis}[
view={100}{35},
width=255pt,
height=255pt,
z buffer=sort,
xlabel={$R$},
ylabel={$G$},
zlabel={$B$},
point meta=explicit,colormap/bluered,
scatter/use mapped color={ball color=mapped color},
]
\addplot3[only marks,scatter,mark size=2.5,
scatter/classes= {0={mark=ball, }}]
table[x=R,y=G,z=B,meta=C] {Scatterplot.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Caption}
\label{label}
 \end{figure}
 \end{document}
```

In this try the data in `Scatterplot.txt` was divide in the following way:

```
R G B C
0.68235 0.67843 0.44314 1
0.68235 0.67451 0.45098 1
0.68235 0.67059 0.4549 2
0.67843 0.66667 0.4549 5
0.68235 0.67451 0.45882 4
0.68235 0.68235 0.46275 3
0.6902 0.69412 0.47451 2
```

It plotted the scatter plot like I wanted. The dots were in the colour cube and had 5 different colours. Those colours were just the ones defined by a predefined colourmap.

The problem is now, that i want to have the marker in a colour specified by three columns in `Scatterplot.txt`.

The file `Scatterplot.txt` now looks like:

```
R G B RED GREEN BLUE
0.68235 0.67843 0.44314 0.7653 0.74446 0.33547
0.68235 0.67451 0.45098 0.7653 0.74446 0.33547
0.68235 0.67059 0.4549 0.7653 0.74446 0.33547
0.67843 0.66667 0.4549 0.7653 0.74446 0.33547
0.68235 0.67451 0.45882 0.7653 0.74446 0.33547
0.68235 0.68235 0.46275 0.7653 0.74446 0.33547
0.6902 0.69412 0.47451 0.7653 0.74446 0.33547
```

So instead of 4 columns with 3 coordinates and a single "colourvalue" I want to have the markers still at the coordinates of the first 3 columns, but coloured in the rgb value defined in the last 3 columns.

This is the first question I asked here and i hope that it is in the format how you normally do this here. If not please let me know so I can do it better next time.

Note, that i found the question

[How to plot scatter points using pgfplots with color defined from table rgb values](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/197270/how-to-plot-scatter-points-using-pgfplots-with-color-defined-from-table-rgb-valu)

which is similar to mine, but I was not able to make it work with a

```
addplot3
```

command.

Comment: I found this post too, but the problem was, that this worked with a `addplot` and not an `addplot3` command. I tried to use the commands in the question you posted, but they didnt worked.

Comment: Then it would have been nice, if you would have added that to the question ... To make life easier for us helpers, please edit your question and provide some *real* values to the `Scatterplot.txt`. (This can also be dummy values.)

Comment: Just copying the optional arguments of the `\addplot` command from <http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197560/95441> and append them to your `\addplot3` command works perfectly fine, when you delete `meta=C` from the `table` options (because in the table there is no column named "C").  If you still need assistance please let us know what exactly isn't working. Do you get an error message or is the output not as you expect and if so, could you add a screenshot to the question and describe, what you mean should be different.

Comment: Thank you verry much. I just made the mistake to not delete the meta=c. I thought i need to "tell" latex to use those columns as rgb values. It works fine now. 
It could be closed.